# Clicking on button in Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I am new in Cypress testing and have issue with click and checking whether the button is disabled or not:

```
export const GoogleLoginButtonPure = ({ isInProgress, login }: AllProps) => {
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => login(), [login]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <GoogleButton
      data-cy="GoogleButton"
      disabled={isInProgress}
      onClick={handleClick}
      fullWidth
      variant="contained"
      startIcon={GOOGLE_ICON}
    >
      {t('login.button')}
    </GoogleButton>
  );
};
```

which I want to test in the following way:

```
  it('login button should be disabled with wrong credentails', () => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '**/api/*/login',
      status: 401,
      response: 'Unauthorized',
      delay: 500,
    }).as('getWrongUser');

    // check disabled button here:
    cy.get('[data-cy=GoogleButton]')
      .click()
      .should('be.disabled');

    cy.checkReduxState('login', 'loginInProgress');

    cy.wait('@getWrongUser').then(() => {
      cy.checkReduxState('login', 'loginError');
    });
    cy.pause();
  })
```

I have no idea why when I write:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=GoogleButton]')
  .click()
```

test works, but when I have:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=GoogleButton]')
  .click()
  .should('be.disabled');
```

Test did not work. When I have added `wait` between `click` and `should` I got:

[image]

Here is Network view:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it taking some time before the button is disabled? If you place a .wait(1000) before .should, is it working then?

Comment: I have updated the question, unfortunately did not work.I was trying with 1000 and then 2000.

Comment: cy.route should be configured before `cy.visit`

Comment: cy.route is already configured, could you suggest solution?

Comment: I meant before the `page loads`. Not just before `cy.click()`. From you test screenshot, I cannot see a `request` log after `click`..can you check if you can see the request in the `Network` tab?

Comment: You are right, there is no /login call in the Network tab. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you try moving the `cy.get('[data-cy=GoogleButton]').should('be.disabled');` inside `.then`?

Comment: @Sree.Bh Do you have maybe some working example of wrapping buttons into .then()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215597/discussion-between-sree-bh-and-tomasz-waszczyk).